# Do I need to Re-Install El Capitan

Tags: imac, security, malware

I have recently acquired my first Apple product: an iMac running El Capitan.

I let a security firm scan my computer and even though nothing has changed I feel compromised.  Others have suggested I reinstall it but I don't want to.

I feel that they put the virus into the website I was trying to download something from just to  get me on the phone.  But I got so upset and said I didn't have £199 that she withdrew the remote support and kept telling me to get a glass of water.

I believed my brand new beautiful machine was broken.  I am now  worried about using it in case they did something to it whilst they were in there.

I am now paranoid:

- can they see me through the camera,
- do they have my keystrokes monitored and
- do they know my passwords.
- Can I do purchases and internet banking on that computer again?

Because she did withdraw when she realised that I had no money at all, I offered a tenner because I don't get paid until Wednesday I told her. 
I think it was maybe just to get me in there and there might not be any other virus except the one that flashed on Safari and wouldn't move until I phoned the number.

And they want the custom but have dodgy means of getting the custom.  As I don't know and it's playing on my mind and has tainted everything.

Any advice, feedback, help support would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a wall of text and hurts me to read it - please reformat and use sentences capital letters etc so we can follow what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reinstall El Capitan (or other recent versions of OS X), reboot the system and press <kbd>Cmd-R</kbd> during reboot. This brings the system up in Recovery mode which allows you to reinstall the OS.

In case you got your iMac second-hand, the original OS might not be El Capitan and Recovery may install an older version of the OS. You can then upgrade to El Capitan by getting the upgrade from the Mac App Store.